# No semicolon before [] is causing error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax, automatic-semicolon-insertion

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = [10, 20, 30, 40];
console.log([a, b].length)
[a, b].some(function(x) {
  x.push(x.shift())
});
```

I was extremely surprised today when this code caused

```
[a,b].some(function(x){ x.push(x.shift()) });
      ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'some' of undefined
```

Obviously the JavaScript 'auto semicolon insertion' is not working as expected here. But why?

I know you might recommend to use `;` everywhere to avoid something like that, but the question is not about whether it is better to use `;` or not. I would love to know what exactly happens here?

Comment: Look up the rules for Automatic Semicolon Insertion: http://es5.github.io/#x7.9

Comment: Here's the rules - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Comment: Honestly, I think the actual answer is in the above links not in below posted answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When I'm worried about semicolon insertion, I think about what the lines in question would look like without any whitespace between them. In your case, that would be:

```
console.log([a,b].length)[a,b].some(function(x){ etc });
```

Here you're telling the Javascript engine to call `console.log` with the length of `[a,b]`, then to look at index `[a,b]` of the result of that call.

`console.log` returns a string, so your code will attempt to find property `b` of that string, which is undefined, and the call to `undefined.some()` fails.

It's interesting to note that `str[a,b]` will resolve to `str[b]` assuming str is a string. As Kamil points out, `a,b` is a valid Javascript expression, and the result of that expression is simply `b`.

Comment: `arr[a, b]` is not multidimensional array access. It's same as `arr[b]` since `a, b` is valid expression that has the value of the inner expression after the last comma.

Comment: I don't think console.log returns a string.

Answer (score 9):

In general, one could say that implicit semi-colon's can easily fail when defining an array on a new line, because an array defined on a new line is interpreted as a property access of the value of the expression on the previous line.

Javascript does only consider new lines to mark the end of a statement if *not* ending the statement after this new line would cause a parse error. See [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) and [EcmaScript 5 spec](http://es5.github.io/#x7.9) for the exact rules. (Thanks to Rob W and limelights)

What happens is the following:

The code get interpreted as

```
console.log([a,b].length)[a,b].some(function(x){ x.push(x.shift()) });
```

i.e. all as one statement.

Now parse the statement:

`some` is called on the value of `console.log([a,b].length)[a,b]`

the value of `console.log([a,b].length)[a,b]` is computed by taking the returned value of `console.log([a,b].length)` (`undefined`) and then trying to access the property with the name of the value of `a,b`.
`a,b` evaluates to the value of `b` (try it in your console). There's no property with the value of `b` of `undefined`, so the resulting value will be `undefined` as well.

There's no method `some` on `undefined`, hence the error.

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript doesn't treat every line break as a semicolon. It usually treats line
breaks as semicolons only if it can’t parse the code without the semicolons. Basically, JavaScript treats a line break as a semicolon if the next non-space character cannot be interpreted as a continuation of the current statement. [JavaScript - The Definitive Guide: 6th Ed. section 2.4](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=2weL0iAfrEMC&lpg=PP1&pg=PT40#v=onepage&q&f=false)

So, in your case, it is interpreting the line as something like

```
console.log([a,b].length)[a,b].some(function(x){ x.push(x.shift()) });
```

And that is the reason for error. JavaScript is trying to perform array-access on the results of `console.log([a,b].length)`. Depending on the JavaScript engine and the return value of `console.log`, you might get different errors.

Answer (score 1):

If it is the last statement of the function or flow, you can avoid `';'` but it is recommended to put `';'` at the end of the each statement to avoid such error.