# Swapping variable JS

Tags: javascript

I swap variable using this way:

```js
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
[a, b] = [b, a];
```

Why this way only works with semicolon at the end? Meanwhile JS works normally without semicolon.

Comment: In this case js wont be able to understand the termination of the code

Comment: Can you explain for more detail?

Comment: JS has something called ASI (automatic semicolon insertion) which isn't really [a feature but an error facility to fix the places where semi-colons haven't been inserted](https://brendaneich.com/2012/04/the-infernal-semicolon/). That article is from the guy who invented JavaScript if you're unsure of its provenance.

Comment: You can't reference `b` as value for `a` because it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Sorry, i edited my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No semicolon before \[\] is causing error in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664824/no-semicolon-before-is-causing-error-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

This is because this part of the code:

```
let b = a
[a, b] = [b, a]
```

Is interpreted as:

```
let b = a[a, b] = [b, a]
```

Which means:

```
let b;          // Create variable b.

b = a[b];       // Assign to b the value of property b of a
                // for example if the value of b is "hello"
                // then b = a.hello. If the value of b is 0
                // then b = a[0];

a[b] = [b, a];  // Assign the array containing b and a to
                // property b of a. For example if the
                // value of b is "hello" then
                // a.hello = ["hello", a]

b = a[b];       // Assign the property b of a to b. For example
                // if the value of b is originally "hello" then
                // b = a.hello
```

Why is this? It's because of how line endings work in javascript. The algorithm is called automatic semicolon insertion. In javascript the end of line is not the end of a statement. This allows us to write multi-line statements. However if the end of line happens to be the end of a statement then javascript will automatically insert a semicolon.

An example of how this works. If javascript sees:

```
let a
let b
```

It will first try to parse it as:

```
let a let b
```

This is of course a syntax error. So javascript will try to insert a semicolon at the end of line and try again:

```
let a;
let b
```

This leads to it being parsed as:

```
let a; let b
```

Which is valid syntax so javascript is happy.

However, say you give javascript this code:

```
let a
[a, b] = [10 20]
```

Javascript will try to parse it as:

```
let a[a, b] = [10 20]
```

This is valid syntax since `a[x]` is just accessing the property `x` of `a`. But what about the comma? It is still valid syntax. It is called the comma operator. The comma operator is an operator just like `+` or `-`. The way the comma operator works is:

1. evaluate the left side of the comma then ignore the result
2. evaluate the right of the comma then return the result.

So the code:

```
a = 1, 2
```

Is the same as:

```
1
a = 2
```

This may seem completely useless but it is sometimes useful (only sometimes - most people never find a use for it). But, it is part of javascript syntax so the code:

```
a[a,b]
```

is valid syntax. It just means `a[b]`.

So javascript has a different understanding of your code than you do.

Removing semicolon from javascript code was popularized by the standard.js project. If you want to use javascript without semicolons **YOU MUST FOLLOW STANDARD.JS RULES**. Otherwise do what I do and always use semicolons.

You can find rules for how not to use semicolons at: https://standardjs.com/rules.html#semicolons

It includes rules like:

> Never start a line with (, [, `, or a handful of other unlikely possibilities.

Standard.js wants you to write your code like this:

```
let a = 1
let b = 2
;[a, b] = [b, a]   // <<------- semicolon at start of this line!!
```

Personally I prefer seeing semicolon at the end of every line but that's up to you.

Answer (score -3):

You can use here the simple method.

```
let a = x;
let b = y;
let temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

I think it's best and fast method.

Comment: This does not answer the question and is in fact an inferior version of the code in the quesiton.